# Creating a pie chart from return data

Tags: python

I created a variable of log returns for a school project and need to now make a pie chart of that broken down to percentage of returns that are:

- <= -0.02
- -0.02 <= returns < = 0
- etc.

Is there an easy way to group the data in my variable and then plot it on the pie chart?

Comment: Can we see what your data looks like?

Comment: I have tried to structure what you want to do..Please see if it helps.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mainly need to group these various return percentage classes.
Assuming you have all this going in a dataframe, you can create a new column say Return_category and give 4 classes for your return levels.
Then you need to count how much each of these classes has
Then you can plot the pie chart..

```
df['Return_Category'] = np.where(df['Pct'] <= -0.2, 'Very Negative',
                                                 np.where(df['Pct'] <=0, 'Marginally Negative',
                                                          np.where(df['Pct'] <= 0.2, 'Marginally Positive', 'Very Positive')))

counts = df['Return_Category'].value_counts()

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Data to plot
labels = 'Very Negative', 'Marginally Negative', 'Marginally Positive', 'Very Positive'
sizes = counts
colors = ['gold', 'yellowgreen', 'lightcoral', 'lightskyblue']
explode = (0.1, 0, 0, 0)  # explode 1st slice

# Plot
plt.pie(sizes, explode=explode, labels=labels, colors=colors,
    autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=140)

plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```